# How to modify a data structure while a process is already accessing it ?

Tags: c++, multithreading, data-structures, multiprocessing

I have written a program (suppose X) in c++ which creates a data structure and then uses it continuously.
Now I would like to modify that data structure without aborting the previous program.
I tried 2 ways to accomplish this task :

1. In the same program X, first I created data structure and then tried to create a child process which starts accessing and using that data structure for some purpose. The parent process continues with its execution and asks the user for any modification like insertion, deletion, etc and takes input from console and subsequently modification is done. The problem here is, it doesn't modify the copy of data structure that the child process was using. Later on, I figured out this won't help because the child process is using its own copy of data structure and hence modifications done via parent process won't be reflected in it.  But definitely, I didn't want this to happen. So I went for multithreading.
2. Instead of creating child process, I created an another thread which access that data structure and uses it and tried to take user input from console in different thread. Even, 
   this didn't work because of very fast switching between threads.

So, please help me to solve this issue. I want the modification to be reflected in the original data structure. Also I don't want the process (which is accessing and using it continuously) to wait for sometimes since it's time crucial.

Comment: http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html, read about shared memory and IPC, sure will help

Comment: So, you want concurrent access to the same data structure? how about synchonizing your access?

Comment: What is the problem with the second approach? I didn't understand.

Comment: I think he is not synchronizing the threads

Comment: @lvella : The thread which is supposed to take user input can't wait and the other thread starts executing. This switching is very fast.

Comment: You can use pthread_join(targetThread,NULL) to wait a thread to finish

Comment: @DGomez : I can't make the thread(suppose A) which is using the data structure to wait since it's very much time crucial. Actually I want, right from the moment, the modification is made in original data structure , thread A will use the modified one only.

Comment: If neither thread can wait then you need a wait-free data structure/algorithm. You can see if one exists that meets your needs. However it seems likely to me that you don't actually need this and just using properly synchronized access, or a lock-free data structure at most, would work. But I can't really tell without knowing more details about your problem.

Comment: @bames53 : I can't make thread A to wait. The approach 1st in the question is pretty fine only if it was the case that the modification is reflected in original data structure.So, I am thinking of something like that.

Answer (score 0):

First point: this is *not* a trivial problem. To handle it at all well, you need to design a *system*, not just a quick hack or two.

First of all, to support the dynamic changing, you'll almost certainly want to define the data structure in code in something like a DLL or .so, so you can load it dynamically.

Part of how to proceed will depend on whether you're talking about data that's stored strictly in memory, or whether it's more file oriented. In the latter case, some of the decisions will depend a bit on whether the new form of a data structure is larger than an old one (i.e., whether you can upgrade in place or no).

Let's start out simple, and assume you're only dealing with structures in memory. Each data item will be represented as an object. In addition to whatever's needed to access the data, each object will provide locking, and a way to build itself from an object of the previous version of the object (lazily -- i.e., on demand, not just in the ctor).

When you load the DLL/.so defining a new object type, you'll create a collection of those the same size as your current collection of existing objects. Each new object will be in the "lazy" state, where it's initialized, but hasn't really been created from the old object yet.

You'll then kick off a thread that walks makes the new collection known to the rest of the program, then walks through the collection of new objects, locking an old object, using it to create a new object, then destroying the old object and removing it from the old collection. It'll use a fairly short timeout when it tries to lock the old object (i.e., if an object is in use, it won't wait for it very long, just go on to the next. It'll iterate repeatedly until all the old objects have been updated and the collection of old objects is empty.

For data on disk, things *can* be just about the same, except your collections of objects provide access to the data on disk. You create two separate files, and copy data from one to the other, converting as needed.

Another possibility (especially if the data can be upgraded in place) is to use a single file, but embed a version number into each record. Read some raw data, check the version number, and use appropriate code to read/write it. If you're reading an old version number, read with the old code, convert to the new format, and write in the new format. If you don't have space to update in place, write the new record to the end of the file, and update the index to indicate the new position.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to concurrent access is similar to sharing a cake between a classroom full of blindfolded toddlers. It's no surprise that you end up with a sticky mess. Each toddler will either have to wait their turn to dig in or know exactly which part of the cake she alone can touch.

Translating to code, the former means having a lock or [mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) that controls access to a data structure so that only one thread can modify it at any time.

The latter can be done by having a data structure that is modified in place by threads that each know exactly which parts of the data structure they can update, e.g. by passing a struct with details on which range to update, effectively splitting up the data beforehand. These should not overlap and iterators should not be invalidated (e.g. by resizing), which may not be possible for a given problem.

There are many many algorithms for handling resource competition, so this is grossly simplified. [Distributed computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing) is a significant field of computer science dedicated to these kinds problems; study the problem (you didn't give details) and don't expect magic.